# Some creatures have unbelievably high ACs in the 40s, but how is that even possible to hit?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, monsters, armor-class

I'm looking at creatures in the [d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/index.htm) and seeing monsters that have really high AC, like 45.

Is that the correct AC or is it supposed to be something else? And if it is correct, then how is anyone supposed to hit it?

Comment: Looking at the original version before Oblivious Sage's edit (which is a reasonable guess, but still may be incorrect), I'm putting this on hold as unclear. The problem may be in fact that they're playing an edition where AC 45 *is* impossible imagine ever hitting and they're mistakenly reading 3.5e material that does not apply to them, and if so that's integral to any correct answer. **Rexingar, what edition of D&D are you playing?**

Comment: I've restored the original tag, to avoid confusing users in the review queues about why this is closed / will be reclosed if reopened without OP clarification.

Answer (score 9):

**Is that the correct AC?**

Yes.

**How is anyone supposed to hit it?**

- A natural 20 on the attack dice always hits
- Some attacks use Touch AC (which is usually nowhere near that high)
- Many spells do not require a to-hit roll (area effect, "save-or-suck", etc)
- At higher levels, you can hit those ACs fairly easily. If you focus on an attribute, you can raise it to 36 by level 20. If that's Str, you'll have +13 on your attack roll. If you're a full-BAB class (eg fighter), you'll have another +20. You're likely to have a strong magical weapon by then, giving up to another +5. That's +38 before you roll, not taking into account feats (eg, *Weapon Focus*), class features, or temporary effects (from spells, potions, etc)

Comment: Don't forget about characters with high BABs to begin with...+20 BAB + a good roll + the other attack bonuses a level 20 martial character will have can hit such creatures...

Comment: Using typical options available to most characters, the high-end 20th-level value of ability scores is 36 (18 + 2 race + 5 levels + 5 inherent + 6 enhancement), for a +23 modifier. Maybe you’re not a +Str race, maybe 18’s too expensive when you have Con to worry about; call it +21. If that’s in Strength, and on a full-BAB character, that’s a +41 bonus right there. Figure *at least* +1 on the weapon, and that character hits AC 45 on a roll of **3**. No need for touch attacks or spells.

Comment: An ability score of 36 is a +13 modifier, not a +23 modifier. However, even losing +10 off the bonus, you can generally assume a +4 or +5 weapon at the level these monsters might be encountered, potentially feats or flanking for some other plusses, and that's before class features.

Comment: @Forrestfire: And let's not forget temporary buffs either (Potion of Heroism, singing Bard, ...) or even True Strike.